# PHP MySQL Date diff

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I have the field `datetime` with DATETIME type in MySQL. In PHP script I set date begin and date end like this: 11/12/1999 and 11/12/2001. In my table datetime saved in the next format: 11.11.1888 00:00:00. How can I compare these dates?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a code sample that shows how you "set date begin and date end"? And why 1888?

Comment: It is an example numbers. What code? I am asking a code.

Comment: So your question is "How to find entries between a start date and an end date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done more easly, but this is one way:

```
$begindate = strreplace($begindate,'/','.');
$enddate = strreplace($enddate,'/','.');

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE dateField BETWEEN '$begindate 00:00:00' AND '$enddate 23:59:59'");
```

Answer (score 1):

should be something like

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(datetime,'%d.%m.%Y') as newdatetime
FROM table
WHERE newdatetime >= STR_TO_DATE('11/12/1999','%d/%m/%Y')
AND newdatetime <= STR_TO_DATE('11/12/2001','%d/%m/%Y');
```